# How can I remove an attribute from an element in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, events, dom-events, self-destruction

How can I remove an attribute (or at least its value) using Angular? In specific, lets say I have an `ng-click` event. I want this even to only fire once and I think the easiest way to do this would be to have a 'self-destruct' in the ng-click event. Something along the lines of

```
elementClicked = function(){
    //do work
    element.ngClick=null;

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Removing ng-click attribute will not work, because click event listener will still be there after removing attribute. You need to set ng-click binding to null.

I created *click-once* directive. It listens element click event and executes ng-click binding for the first time, then it removes it.

```
.directive('clickOnce', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      'ngClick': '&'
    },
    link: function(scope, element) {
      element.bind('click', function() {
        if (scope.ngClick) {
          scope.ngClick();
          scope.ngClick = null;
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Here is the markup:

```
<button click-once ng-click="doThis()>my button<button>
```

Here is [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9p57ouge/2/).

Comment: Just curious, what's the use case please?

Comment: Thanks for the edit @vjarysta. I think it should have been accepted :)